# Can I call a constructor from same class method in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Can I call a `constructor` from same class method in `C#`?

Example:

```
class A
{
    public A()
    {
        /* Do Something here */
    }

    public void methodA()
    {
        /* Need to call Constructor here */
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you create a new instance of class A within `methodA` and then use that new, temporary instance?

Comment: If the constructor does something that you need to call at other times as well then that should probably be in its own method and you should call _that_ method from `methodA`.

Comment: Actually I have connection string in the constructor and it is timed out at certain stage and to avoid the timed out error I need to call the constructor in the methodA

Comment: You have a problem with your code structure.  Why do you have the connection string in the constructor?

Comment: If you want help with a concrete problem (rather than spending time speculating about possible solutions you've thought up), please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is **No** :)

You cannot call constructors as simple methods **except** these special cases:

1. You create a new object: `var x = new ObjType()`
2. You call a constructor from another constructor of the same type:

   ```
    class ObjType
    {
        private string _message;

        // look at _this_ being called before the constructor body definition
        public ObjType() :this("hello")
        {}

        private ObjType(string message)
        {
            _message = message;
        }
    }
   ```
3. You call a base type constructor from a constructor:

   ```
    class BaseType 
    {
        private string _message;

        // NB: should not be private
        protected BaseType(string message)
        {
            _message = message;
        }
    }

    class ObjType : BaseType
    {
        // look at _base_ being called before the constructor body execution
        public ObjType() :base("hello")
        {}
    }
   ```

**UPD**. Regarding the workaround with an initialization method proposed in another answer - yes, it's probably a good way. But it's a bit tricky because of the object consistency, which is the reason why constructors are even exist. Any object method is expected to receive the object (`this`) in a consistent (working) state. And you cannot guarantee it calling a method from a constructor. So any person editing that initialization method or calling constructor in future (probably you) could expect having this guarantee which greatly increases the risk of making mistake. The problem is amplified when you deal with inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Besides provided answer which answers the question, an easy away to fix your problem is to define an initialization method that is called from both the constructor and your method:

```
class A
{
    private init()
    {
       // do initializations here
    }

    public A()
    {
        init();
    }
    public void methodA()
    {
        // reinitialize the object
        init();

        // other stuff may come here
    }
}
```

Shortly put, **you cannot call the constructor, but you don't have to** :)